# Calling one controller's method in another controller?

Tags: sapui5

I am totally confused with all the buzzwords you all are using modules, eventbus.

I will try to rephrase my question in more simple words because I am new to this framework and I like to understand it in simple way. So here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have a Questionnaire controller which is binded to Questionnaire view. Now I need to fetch some data from my backend with my xsjs and bind to this view. I need to fetch this data before the page renders so I am using my ajax call in Before Rendering and in the complete property of my ajax call I need to perform some vaildations. As my function in complete property is too long I was thinking of creating a separate controller and then defining my method which makes ajax call and necessary validations here. This new controller just holds this method definition hence it is not binded to any view.

Now How should I call this controller in the Questionnaire controller and use its method that makes the ajax call and performs the validations in controller method?

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
"sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
"sap/m/MessageBox"], function(Controller, JSONModel, MessageBox) {


var questionnaireResponseId;
var password;
var backendJSON;

Controller.extend("OnlineQuestionnaire.controller.Questionnaire", {

    onInit: function() {
        jQuery.sap.require("jquery.sap.storage");

    },
    onBeforeRendering: function() {
        questionnaireResponseId = jQuery.sap.storage.get("QuestionnaireResponseId");
        password = jQuery.sap.storage.get("Password");
       backendJSON = loadStack(questionnaireResponseId);  //This is not correct way to call 
}
```

This method is defined in QuestionStack.controller.js

```
loadStack(questionnaireResponseId) {
jQuery.ajax({
                url: "",
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                complete: this.onSuccess,
                error: this.onErrorCall
            });


return output;
}
```

Comment: If the other controller is not binded to any view then why is it a controller? Isn't it just a reusable module?

Comment: kind of a module to hold extra code and reduce code complexity in my Questionnaire.controller.js

Comment: Method onBeforeRendering is not the place to load data. You should use the routing mechanism and perform data load when a specific route has matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extend your QuestionStack.controller.js with Questionnare.controller.js:

```
sap.ui.define([
".." // path to your QuestionStack.controller.js, e.g. "myapp/controller/QuestionStack"
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
"sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
"sap/m/MessageBox"], function(Controller, JSONModel, MessageBox) {


var questionnaireResponseId;
var password;
var backendJSON;

QuestionStack.extend("OnlineQuestionnaire.controller.Questionnaire", { // extend
    ..
}
```

call the method with this.loadStack(..);

Comment: In this way, you will load the COMPLETE controller. This may cause performance issues, if your project reaches a certain state! please don't do this. I'll provide another approach.

Comment: see loki's comment: "kind of a module to hold extra code and reduce code complexity in my Questionnaire.controller.js". says it all. extend is exactly what is right. but out of interest, which state needs your project to reach, that extend causes performance issues?